# IOS Core Data asynchronous saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

## Problem Statement

I am having trouble saving server side data **asynchronously**.

## Structure

I am using the following structure of NSManagedObjectContext in order of parent to child:

1. writerManagedObjectContext (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
2. masterManagedObjectContext (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType)
3. backgroundManagedObjectContext (NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType)

## Code

I am using the following code to save data

```
[backgroundManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    [backgroundManagedObjectContext save:nil];
    [masterManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{ // Starts blocking UI from here
        [masterManagedObjectContext save:nil];
        [writerManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            [writerManagedObjectContext save:nil];
        }]
    }]
}]
```

## Problem

The code saves fine. The `backgroundManagedObjectContext` also saves asynchronously. However, both `masterManagedObjectContext` and `writerManagedObjectContext` refuse to be saved asynchronously and blocks the UI thread. (I know it blocks the UI thread because I tried to perform actions which have nothing to do with Core Data and they were also blocked. This is not a case of the persistent coordinator not being accessible)

## Questions

1. What would be the reason the above code blocks the main thread?
2. Am I correct in assuming I can call the above code from anywhere since the `save` will be called in each respective thread/context?

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit**

http://floriankugler.com/2013/04/29/concurrent-core-data-stack-performance-shootout/

Apparently the freeze comes from the attempt to propagate to the parent NSManagedObjectContext. The article seems to elude to the fact that it is impossible to have a truly asynchronous save to the main context.

The data was heavily linked, 5MB, and took approximately 40s to save to psc. I don't think I'll use a parallel structure as described in the post since the code base is already large as it is. I would appreciate any strategies I can utilize to decrease this freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `backgroundManagedObjectContext` is a private queue context it still propagates its changes up to `masterManagedObjectContext`, being its parent.   This could be where it's choking up.   Merging changes from child contexts still takes up CPU time, the effects of which become more pronounced in a busy queue like the UI's.

You can always use Instruments to analyze what's going on.

If your particular use case permits, try setting `backgroundManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator` to the same psc as `writerManagedObjectContext` and not make it a child of `masterManagedObjectContext`.

Better yet, use an awesome framework like [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord).  Doesn't shield you from problems like this, but less code makes things (arguably) a bit easier to debug.

Comment: I'm already using nested MOCs as shown by the structure. My question is why the save isn't asynchronous despite using a nested MOC structure.

Comment: I realised you were using nested contexts after re-reading your post.   I'll edit my answer.   You should avoid passing `nil` to the `save` error handler.   You'll want to be able to react to errors.   Try checking for errors and see if that's what stalling your main queue.   Also you mentioned 'server side'.   Are you using Core Data iCloud syncing?

Comment: I'm using my own server, but honestly the server is irrelevant. Basically I am parsing json data and inserting them to Core Data. I am doing error handling -- the code above is just to illustrate what my code looks like.

Comment: I tried periodically pausing during syncing to see what's stalling my main queue and I can only see the data progressively saving. I guess I just can't save completely asynchronously using this structure. It's a little frustrating given how it was so easy in android=(

Comment: Yep... That's what I was suspecting.. The link on my edited question also eludes to your answer. I'll probably end up carefully choosing when to save my main moc. Discussing this with you was very helpful! Thanks=)